# Prove $s$ is a supremum iff for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists $a\in A$ such that $a>s-\epsilon$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, proof-verification, solution-verification

Let $A\subseteq\Bbb{R}$ is a nonempty set and $s\in \Bbb{R}$ is an upper bound. Prove $s$ is the supremum iff for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists $a\in A$ such that $a>s-\epsilon$.
This is important to me to know I am correct in my attempt, because I always grant more when I do try.

**Attempt:** Suppose for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists $a\in A$ such that $a>s-\epsilon$. Assume $s$ is not the supremum. Then, since the supremum exists, let $s_1$ be the supremum. By the density of the real number,there exists $c$ such that $s_1<c<s$. Let us pick $\epsilon_1$ such that $s=c+\epsilon_1$ $\color{red}\Rightarrow c=s-\epsilon_1$ $\color{red}{\Rightarrow} s_1<s-\epsilon_1<s$ $\color{red}{\Rightarrow}$ $s>s_1+\epsilon_1$. Since for $\epsilon_1$ there exists $a\in A$ such that $a>s-\epsilon_1$. In particular $a>s_1+\epsilon_1-\epsilon_1$ meaning $a>s_1$. A contradiction. Therefore, $s$ is the supremum.

Now, suppose, $s$ is the supremum. Assume there exists $\epsilon$ such that for all $a\in A$, $a<s-\epsilon$. That would mean that $s-\epsilon$ is an upper bound that is smaller than $s$. A contradiction. Therefore, for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists $a\in A$ such that $a>s-\epsilon$.

Comment: It looks just fine to me. Very good. +1

Comment: Thank you for your evaluation. It is important to me.

Comment: For the first part of the proof, with $s_1<s ,$ you can simply take $\epsilon=(s-s_1)/2>0$. Then for some $a\in A$ we have $a>s-\epsilon=s-(s-s_1)/2=(s+s_1)/2>s_1,$ contradicting the supposition that $s_1$ is an upper bound for $A.$...( This does not mean you made any mistakes.  Actually, many published papers are presentations of simpler proofs of earlier results.)

Comment: I am doing the same question here, got a question might be dumb, but for part one, why does $s$ would necessarily be another upper bound. From the premises, $\forall \epsilon >0,$ exists $a\in A$ such that $a>s-\epsilon$ it seems $s$ could not be another lower bound.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Why can't we simplify even more and just take $\epsilon = s - s_1 > 0$? Then for some $a \in A$, $a > s_1$ which contradicts assumption that $s_1$ is an upper bound for $A$.

Comment: @oskarryn . Yes... Good..............

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks great! There's a couple things that I might improve on to make some of the steps clearer. As a matter of personal taste, I would be be a bit more explicit about what exactly is being contradicted and I would try avoiding implications (preferring instead to chain them together when possible). Here's my version.

---

Given any nonempty $A \subseteq \mathbb R$, suppose that $s \in \mathbb R$ is an upper bound for $A$ so that $s \geq a'$ for all $a' \in A$ and (by the completeness property of $\mathbb R$) $A$ has some supremum, say $s' \in \mathbb R$. We will show that $s = s'$ iff for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists some $a \in A$ such that $a > s - \epsilon$.

- $(\Longrightarrow)$: Suppose that $s = s'$. Now suppose, towards a contradiction, that there exists some $\epsilon > 0$ such that for any $a \in A$, we have that $a \leq s - \epsilon$. Then $s - \epsilon$ is an upper bound for $A$. But since $s - \epsilon < s'$, this contradicts the minimality of $s'$, as $s'$ is supposed to be the **least** such upper bound. So for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists some $a \in A$ such that $a > s - \epsilon$, as desired.
- $(\Longleftarrow)$: Suppose that for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists some $a \in A$ such that $a > s - \epsilon$. Now suppose, towards a contradiction, that $s \neq s'$. Then since $s'$ is the **least** upper bound, we know that $s' < s$. Thus, by the density of $\mathbb R$, we know that there exists some $c \in \mathbb R$ such that $s' < c < s$. Now for $\epsilon = s - c > 0$, we know by hypothesis that there exists some $a \in A$ such that $a > s - \epsilon = s - (s - c) = c > s'$. Hence, $s'$ was not actually an upper bound for $A$, contradicting the definition of a supremum. So $s = s'$, as desired. $~~\blacksquare$

Comment: Question for you @Adriano (or anyone else):  I know that since if  $s'$ is a supremum, then it is less than or equal to any other upper bound.  Does the fact that $s'$ is a *least* upper bound mean $s' \lt s$?  or does it just mean $s' \le s$?  
 I usually see $s' \le s$.  e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upper_and_lower_bounds.  Or doesthe density of real numbers property still apply regardless of whetehre it's < or $\le$?

Comment: Yes, if $s'$ is a least upper bound for $A$ and if $s$ is an upper bound for $A$, then $s' \leq s$. In my proof, we were supposing towards a contradiction that $s \neq s'$, which is why I stated that $s' < s$.

Comment: Right, but you can only use the “density of $\mathbb{R}$” property if the inequality is strict.  So I think the OPs answer is not complete, right?  It neglects the case where $s=s’$

Comment: Do we have to use the density of $\mathbb{R}$? you assumed $\forall \epsilon > 0$, there exists some $a \in A$ st. $a > s -  \epsilon$, so take $ \epsilon = s - s'$, then by the assumption there exists some $a \in A$ st. $ a > s - (s - s') = s'$, which contradicts $s'$ being a supremum.